# java:Why is full GC called when -Xms and -Xmx are unequal?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was reading a doc on java GC

> A memory space, either Old or Permanent, is full and to accommodate new objects or classes, it needs 
>   to be expanded towards its max size, if the relevant parameters have different values. In other words, if 
>   ‐Xms and ‐Xmx have different values and if the size of Old needs be increased from ‐Xms towards ‐Xmx 
>   to accommodate more objects, a FullGC is called. Similarly, if ‐XX:PermSize and ‐XX:MaxPermSize have 
>   different values and the Permanent Space needs to be increased towards ‐XX:MaxPermSize to 
>   accommodate new java classes, a FullGC is called. This can be avoided by always setting ‐Xms and ‐Xmx 
>   as well as ‐XX:PermSize and ‐XX:MaxPermSize to the same value.

Wondering why is a FullGC called in this case? Whats the use?

Answer (score 2):

Resizing the heap is not just a matter of adding more memory. There is data structures the GC uses which have to be resized and this requires a FullGC to be preformed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

- -Xms and -Xmx does not determine the amount of memory your application needs.
- If -Xms value is different then -Xmx, full GC is called in order to
  resize the heap to fulfill your memory requirement of your application.
- If the above parameters are same, the resizing will be avoided
  altogether, because your application launches with a heap which is
  big enough for it. In short, you are saying to JVM, my application will never need heap bigger than this.